# Jmeter 406 error - token not found

Tags: cookies, jmeter, token, http-status-code-406

I'm using Jmeter for the first time to test the Load from a website. But there are exactly 3 API's that don't seem to work. The three of them have the same error page at the View Results Tree (I translated the error message to english):

[image]

The Test Plan already has the HTTP Request Defaults, HTTP Cookie Manager, HTTP Header Manager and Recording Controller.

How can I solve that problem or know which is the Token that is missing? Some API's that come **after** it have a Cookie Data called .ASPXAUTH. Is that the token I need?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard to guess without seeing your request and response details, you can identify the required dynamic parameter (token or whatever) by recording your test one more time and compare resulting .jmx files for differences.

Carefully inspect **everything** as the token might come as a [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), as a [Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), as a part of the response URL after redirection or in the response body and use the relevant JMeter's [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract it from the previous response and add to the next request.

The process is known as **correlation** and you should be able to find a plenty of information on different approaches over the web via `jmeter correlation` query in your favorite search engine.

---

You may also be interested in an alternative way of recording a JMeter test which automatically detects and works around dynamic parameters so you won't have to do this manually, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.